# How to retrieve Azure service bus message still in queue when subscriber was down during publish

Tags: azure, message-queue, servicebus

We are trying to use Azure Topic/Subscriptions to distribute changes in one domain to others services that need to update their local cache. So we have one guy publishing a message and a bunch, not knowing of eachother, listening to this topic queue.

I might have missunderstod the idea of the azure TopicDescription.DefaultMessageTimeToLive but I thought it indicated that as long as the message is still within this timeout, it will be delivered, regardless if the subscriber is "online" at the time of publishing.

But this does not seem do be the case?

What I want to accomplish is that if I have a DefaultMessageTimeToLive set to 10 minutes, all subscribers are guaranteed to get all published messages if they have a downtime lower than 10 minutes.

When I try it, I do not receive messages unless I am listening at the time of publishing. *(Added remark: Each receiving queue has its own unique name)*

Have I got it wrong or is there a configuration I missed?

Comment: Do you keep the subscriptions on the topic at all times? (i.e. not manually setting a "IdleTimeout" on the subscription, or re-creating the subscription when the listener comes back online)

Comment: No. The subscription must be allowed to go "down" for a minute or two. That's part of the solution needed..

Comment: It works! It was a human error where a character had found its way in to the queuename. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

If you want a topic available to N subscribers (listeners), then you need N subscriptions.  Subscriptions are "virtual" FIFO queues.  If a subscription has more than one listener, they "compete" for the next message. This pattern is often termed the “competing consumer” pattern. Read more at [Service Bus Queues, Topics, and Subscriptions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh367516.aspx) and [How to Use Service Bus Topics/Subscriptions](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-bus-dotnet-how-to-use-topics-subscriptions/).

The TopicDescription.DefaultMessageTimeToLive just defines how long a message is available before it is moved to the dead-letter queue.

Comment: To clearify, I have lets say 5 unique subscriptions to the same topic, with unique names. So for each subscription I seem to miss messages if I'm not running at the time of publishing. So there should be no competition.